# access data in webpage using bastion host from private postgres db in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two instance **"bastion host"** and private **"PostgreSQL db"** instance (private instance or not any ip) .

(all instance in Linux)

Bastion host able to connect PostgreSQL database using ssh.

but I want to access data from postgres db using bastion host inside my webpage or make the connection 
between database and local user without using any third party like(putty or ssh/rdp).

I want to make my database private no one can access directly only allow access throw my bastion host.(important point)

so if u have any idea about just reply

Comment: who is a local user

Comment: where is your web page running

Comment: Just because you mentioned a webpage: Do you want to make HTTP(S) calls to a web application? Do you have such a web application at all? Please make some specifications of the whole picture.

Comment: I want to ,if i make any request using jdbd then how to connect with my database  becouse this private only access with bastian host .i need database host name but it connect thow the bastion host  # the local user is anyone who have the ,hostname,username,port,databasename,password

Comment: Just like we used to make connection to database

Comment: Everything we need to create with scratch